# Is 'allow_url_fopen' required for this/any SOAP call?

Tags: php, curl, soap, soap-client

Could someone please let me know if 'allow_url_fopen' is required to be set to yes/on in order to perform a SOAP call like the below.

If anyone would like anymore information on why I'm aksing this I can provide more but I'm trying to keep the question simple at this stage as at the moment I'm trying to figure out if 'allow_url_fopen' is required for what I'm trying to do.

If it is required could someone please let me know which part specifically requires the 'allow_url_fopen' part and how I might use something else like cURL in order to do what I'm trying to do here.

Thanks in advance guys.

```
$username = 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com';
$password = 'xxxxxxxx';

$profile_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx';

$wsdl = 'https://pilot.id3global.com/ID3gWS/ID3global.svc?wsdl';

class clsWSSEAuth { 
        private $Username; 
        private $Password;  
        function __construct($username, $password) { 
            $this->Username=$username; 
            $this->Password=$password; 
        } 
    } 

    class clsWSSEToken { 
        private $UsernameToken; 
        function __construct ($UsernameToken) { 
            $this->UsernameToken = $UsernameToken; 
        } 
    } 

    $strWSSENS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"; 

    //Auth
    $objSoapVarUser = new SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, NULL, $strWSSENS, NULL, $strWSSENS); 
    $objSoapVarPass = new SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, NULL, $strWSSENS, NULL, $strWSSENS); 
    $objWSSEAuth = new clsWSSEAuth($objSoapVarUser, $objSoapVarPass); 

    //Token
    $objSoapVarWSSEToken = new SoapVar($objWSSEAuth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $strWSSENS, 'UsernameToken', $strWSSENS); 
    $objWSSEToken = new clsWSSEToken($objSoapVarWSSEToken); 

    //Header
    $objSoapVarWSSEAuth = new SoapVar($objWSSEToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $strWSSENS, 'UsernameToken', $strWSSENS); 
    $objSoapVarHeaderVal = new SoapVar($objSoapVarWSSEAuth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $strWSSENS, 'Security', $strWSSENS); 
    $objSoapVarWSSEHeader = new SoapHeader($strWSSENS, 'Security', $objSoapVarHeaderVal, true); 

    //Client
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 
        'trace' => 1, 
        'exception' => true, 
    )); 

    $client->__setSoapHeaders($objSoapVarWSSEHeader);

    // Build data array to use for AML check
    $data = array(xxxxxxxxxxxxx);

// Run the check
    $applicant_1_aml = FALSE;
    try {
        $result = $client->AuthenticateSP(array(
            'ProfileIDVersion' => array('ID' => $profile_id),
            'InputData' => $data,
        ));
        $applicant_1_aml = TRUE;
        $applicant_1_band = $result->AuthenticateSPResult->BandText;
        $applicant_1_score = $result->AuthenticateSPResult->Score;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
        //var_dump($e);
    }
```

Comment: To ask the obvious question, does your code currently run?

Comment: Well I'm glad you asked as this is part of the problem. It did run and ran successfully for around 6months. Then suddenly it stopped working and when ever the SOAP calls were tried I got back a 500 internal server error.

Comment: I can access the WSDL from my browser, so this is not the problem.  Could they have implemented authentication recently?

Comment: Ok maybe, however I'm able to successfully make these SOAP when I setup an exact duplicate on my local machine. Which leads me to believe that authentication has not been added.

Comment: When I say exact duplicate I do mean a duplicate of the live/production site that I have running on my local machine. And the SOAP calls are working there leading me to believe that authentication has not been implemented recently as I can still my the SOAP calls on my local copy.